# richfaces namespace not found on remote server

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am have richfaces 4.5 with JSF 2.2 project. Its not a maven project. I have included the JARs.
The application works fine and richfaces components render properly on my local tomcat 8 instance. I am deploying though eclipse.

Now I exported the project as war file and deployed a remote tomcat 8 instance. My page is blank with below warnings

```
Warning: The page /index.xhtml declares namespace http://richfaces.org/rich and uses the tag rich:chart , but no TagLibrary associated to namespace.
Warning: The page /index.xhtml declares namespace http://richfaces.org/rich and uses the tag rich:chartLegend , but no TagLibrary associated to namespace.
```

I have below JARs in my classpath --

```
richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar
richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar
myfaces-api-2.2.12.jar
myfaces-impl-2.2.12.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
... and other
```

Below is how my tag declaration looks

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
     xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" >

    <h:head>
```

Comment: But are these jars deployed or only on the development local classpath... Check that, easy to do.

Comment: I do see these JARs in .war file